# Does the fact photons having gravity field contradict gravitomagnetism?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, photons

as I read here two photons that aren't parallels can attract each other because  photons have energy. But the problem is that photon are going in the speed of light which means it would take infinity amount of time  to the photon get attract to each other, or in other worlds the gravitomagnetism would be equal to the gravity field and it would cancel out. The idea of gravitomagnetism is that there is a upside "force"  to gravity when mass or in our case energy moves because of relativity. So how come the two photon attract each other relative to observer that doesn't in the speed of light?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of thing I found two way to look at this one is that if they parallel their relative mass relative mass of each photon relative to each other is not zero their reltaive mass is cos sinos the angle between them multiply by hf/c^2